# SSRS / SQL Selective Date MAX questions

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hello we have the following dataset coming out of SQL.

```
NAME, TYPE, DATE
ALICE, 1, 1/1/2001
ALICE, 1, 1/1/2002    
ALICE, 2, 1/1/2003
ALICE, 2, 1/1/2004
BOB,   1, 1/1/2005
BOB,   1, 1/1/2003
```

We need to display the table in an SSRS tablix where we have one row for each user, and one column for each type that displays the most recent date. so

```
NAME,   MOST RECENT TYPE 1 DATE, MOST RECENT TYPE 2 DATE
ALICE,    1/1/2002,               1/1/2004
BOB  ,    1/1/2005,               NONE
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to get the MAX date to only calculate on TYPE 1 or TYPE 2, since the type values are in the same column.

Right now I have row grups to aggregate all of alice and all of bob, but I cant figure out how to segregate out the two different types of dates so I can get the MAX on each type separately.

Any advice?

thanks, 
MC

Comment: Is a SQL query an acceptable answer?

Comment: Will there by other types or just `1` and `2`?

Comment: no , this is a simplified version of the actual table. There are 6 different types.   Right now I can only deal with this table in SSRS, I'm working on having them fix the query a little to make it easier for me, but for the time being this is the data that I have to work with.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Sql Answer IS acceptable, you can do the following:

```
SELECT 
   ud.Name, 
   MAX(CASE ud.Type WHEN 1 THEN ud.SomeDate END) AsMostRecentType1,
   MAX(CASE ud.Type WHEN 2 THEN ud.SomeDate END) AsMostRecentType2
FROM
   UserDates ud
GROUP BY ud.Name;
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19e84/4).

I've resisted the temptation to apply `ISNULL(x, 'NONE')` in SQL, as this poses type issues and IMO is a presentation tier concern and should be [applied in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) at the same time as you decide on your date formatting, e.g.:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!AsMostRecentType1.Value), "NONE", 
     Fields!AsMostRecentType1.Value.ToString("D/M/YYYY"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add a Column Group on your Type column.  Then the default scope of an SSRS Max function (in the detail cell) will be the combination of the Row Group for Name and the Column Group for Type.